# libgazebo segmentation fault in std::_Rb_tree*

Tags: ros, gazebo, player

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I've installed [Gazebo 0.10](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/index.php?src=gazebo) from sources on Kubuntu 11.10 x64, and got a strange segfault on static objects initialization (before main()).

Used libraries: http://pastebin.com/4xAa1WcZ
GDB backtrace: http://pastebin.com/EiRY77Je
ltrace output: http://pastebin.com/9kMyAY67

The app fails here (gazebo-0.10.0/libgazebo/IfaceFactory.cc, static method):

```
using namespace gazebo;

std::map<std::string, IfaceFactoryFn> IfaceFactory::ifaces;

// Register a iface class.  Use by dynamically loaded modules
void IfaceFactory::RegisterIface(std::string classname, IfaceFactoryFn factoryfn)
{
  ifaces[classname] = factoryfn; // segfault in std::_Rb_tree_decrement(..)
}
```

Arguments are okay, stack is not overflowed.

Also look at the [valgrind output](http://pastebin.com/0DXUNGgv): "Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd" - looks like invalid pointer, but arguments passed into the std::map are correct.

Used dependencies: bullet-2.79, fltk-1.1.10, ode-0.11.1, openal-soft-1.13, player-3.0.2, ogre-1.7.3;
flags for bullet: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON, BT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION=ON.

What is my problem?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11634/libgazebo-segmentation-fault-in-std::_rb_tree*/) by [Spym](https://answers.ros.org/users/1256/spym/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2011-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5170

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1